# collapse package: sum over two vectors but keep empty intersections

Tags: r, r-collapse

I would like to aggregate a vector/ matrix y by two variables a and b via the fsum function of the collapse package. fsum does not return values for empty intersections. Is there a way to keep empty intersection using the collapse package? I know that I could e.g. work through cross-joins and data.table, but as my function input is a vector and speed really matters, I would like to avoid converting the input matrix to a data.table and then convert the output back to a matrix / vector (for a solution with data.table, see e.g. here: [data.table calculate sums by two variables and add observations for "empty" groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183352/data-table-calculate-sums-by-two-variables-and-add-observations-for-empty-grou)).

Here is an example:

```
library(collapse)

set.seed(1)
a <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)
y <- matrix(rnorm(10), 10, 1)

fsum(x = y, g = data.frame(a = a, b = b))
#> fsum(x = y, g = data.frame(a = a, b = b))
#           [,1]
#1.1 -0.40955189
#1.2 -0.05710677
#2.2  0.50360797
#2.3 -1.28459935
#3.1  0.04672617
#3.2 -0.69095384
#3.3 -0.23570656
#4.1  0.80418951
#5.2  1.08576936
```

What I would like to get: the regular output above, but keeping the empty intersections of (a, b) - e.g (a = 1, b = 3) and assign a missing or zero:

```
#   a b          y
#1: 1 1 -0.7702614
#2: 1 2 -0.2992151
#3: 1 3         NA
#4: 2 1         NA
#5: 2 2 -0.4115108
#6: 2 3  0.4356833
#.................
```

As an addition: `base::aggregate()` has a function argument `drop = FALSE` that achieves this:

```
aggregate(y, data.frame(a, b), sum, drop = FALSE)
  a b         V1
#1  1 1 -0.7702614
#2  2 1         NA
#3  3 1 -1.2375384
#4  4 1 -0.2894616
#5  5 1         NA
#6  1 2 -0.2992151
#7  2 2 -0.4115108
#8  3 2 -0.8919211
#9  4 2         NA
#10 5 2  0.2522234
#11 1 3         NA
#12 2 3  0.4356833
#13 3 3 -0.2242679
#14 4 3         NA
#15 5 3         NA
```

Nevertheless, in my experience both `data.table` and `collapse` are significantly faster, but`collapse` has the advantage that it also works with matrix objects (that do not need to be converted to data.table's).

Is there away to achieve this via collapse?

Comment: you'd like a data.frame as output??

Comment: Optimally I would like a matrix with dimensions length(unique(a)) and length(unique(b)) as output.

Comment: One way would be to create all the groups either through expand.grid or data.table::CJ, then do a left join. But I don't think that this would be a satisfactory solution for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do that with `fsum`, however other functions like `fmedian` will warn about that. To do that you need to create factors and interact them using `:` like so:

```
library(collapse)

set.seed(1)
a <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)
y <- matrix(rnorm(10), 10, 1)

fsum(x = y, g = qF(a):qF(b))
# [,1]
# 1:1 -0.7702614
# 1:2 -0.2992151
# 1:3         NA
# 2:1         NA
# 2:2 -0.4115108
# 2:3  0.4356833
# 3:1 -1.2375384
# 3:2 -0.8919211
# 3:3 -0.2242679
# 4:1 -0.2894616
# 4:2         NA
# 4:3         NA
# 5:1         NA
# 5:2  0.2522234
# 5:3         NA
```

For the earlier example you gave, I'd also like to note that the expensive call to `data.frame` is absolutely not necessary, `fsum(x = y, g = list(a = a, b = b))` is sufficient.